# Local MongoDB Connection issue using Meteor

Tags: meteor

I need to connect a `Local MongoDB` to `Meteor`. I did a "LeaderBoard" example in which I tried to connect to `Local DB` by using the below procedure:

```
meteor mongo lboard.meteor.com   //Deploy project name is lboard.meteor.com

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: production-db-b3.meteor.io:27017/lboard_meteor_com
```

then i try to switch DB using the below procedure:

```
> use lboard_meteor_com

//This time i got the below error

switched to db lboard_meteor_com
Thu Jan 23 15:09:42.125 trying reconnect to production-db-b3.meteor.io:27017
Thu Jan 23 15:09:48.127 reconnect production-db-b3.meteor.io:27017 failed couldn
't connect to server production-db-b3.meteor.io:27017
```

Also, I get an error in the server console as shown below and I am new to meteor so please have a look at the below and above error and tell me what to do.

**Server Console Error Log & What i am did in server is:**

```
C:\Users\***>e:

E:\>cd ***/meteor/db

E:\***\Meteor\DB>set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/ddhcare_meteor_co
m

E:\**\Meteor\DB>meteor
[[[[[ E:\***\Meteor\DB ]]]]]

=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
W20140124-13:32:29.831(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\.meteor\packag
es\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.j
s:359
W20140124-13:32:29.922(5.5)? (STDERR)           throw err
W20140124-13:32:29.922(5.5)? (STDERR)                 ^
W20140124-13:32:29.924(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: failed to connect to [localhost:270
17]
W20140124-13:32:29.925(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\App
Data\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\l
ib\mongodb\connection\server.js:540:74)
W20140124-13:32:29.925(5.5)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17
)
W20140124-13:32:29.926(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\App
Data\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\l
ib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:140:15)
W20140124-13:32:29.926(5.5)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)

W20140124-13:32:29.927(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\A
ppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb
\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:478:10)
W20140124-13:32:29.927(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js
:95:17)
W20140124-13:32:29.928(5.5)? (STDERR)     at net.js:441:14
W20140124-13:32:29.928(5.5)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:
13)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Meteor server restarted
W20140124-13:32:32.697(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Hari\AppData\Local\.meteor\packag
es\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.j
s:359
W20140124-13:32:32.698(5.5)? (STDERR)           throw err
W20140124-13:32:32.699(5.5)? (STDERR)                 ^
W20140124-13:32:32.700(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: failed to connect to [localhost:270
17]
W20140124-13:32:32.701(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\App
Data\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\l
ib\mongodb\connection\server.js:540:74)
W20140124-13:32:32.701(5.5)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17
)
W20140124-13:32:32.702(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\App
Data\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\l
ib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:140:15)
W20140124-13:32:32.703(5.5)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)

W20140124-13:32:32.703(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\A
ppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb
\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:478:10)
W20140124-13:32:32.704(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js
:95:17)
W20140124-13:32:32.705(5.5)? (STDERR)     at net.js:441:14
W20140124-13:32:32.706(5.5)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:
13)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Meteor server restarted
W20140124-13:32:35.495(5.5)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Hari\AppData\Local\.meteor\packag
es\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\mongo_client.j
s:359
W20140124-13:32:35.497(5.5)? (STDERR)           throw err
W20140124-13:32:35.498(5.5)? (STDERR)                 ^
W20140124-13:32:35.501(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: failed to connect to [localhost:270
17]
W20140124-13:32:35.505(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\App
Data\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\l
ib\mongodb\connection\server.js:540:74)
W20140124-13:32:35.509(5.5)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17
)
W20140124-13:32:35.513(5.5)? (STDERR)     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\App
Data\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb\l
ib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:140:15)
W20140124-13:32:35.517(5.5)? (STDERR)     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)

W20140124-13:32:35.521(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hari\A
ppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\31700cb194\npm\node_modules\mongodb
\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:478:10)
W20140124-13:32:35.526(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js
:95:17)
W20140124-13:32:35.529(5.5)? (STDERR)     at net.js:441:14
W20140124-13:32:35.532(5.5)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:
13)
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a local MongoDB instance you should instead set the `MONGO_URL` environment variable before starting `meteor`:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname
meteor
```

To connect to the local MongoDB instance, you should also use the `mongo` shell rather than `meteor mongo`:

```
$ mongo dbname
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
>
```

Comment: MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname here what is the "dbname" sir , Can you please explain once?.@Stennie

Comment: That's a placeholder for whatever you want your database to be called.  From your question description, it looks like that should be `lboard_meteor_com`.

Comment: This command runs on server console or db shell console.Can you please explain once?.@Stennie

Comment: The export command setting the `MONGO_URL` environment variable runs on server console (i.e. `bash` shell, or whatever your default is)

Comment: I tried server console but i got error i.e E:\***\Meteor\DB>export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/lboard_meteor_com
`'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`.So Can you please solve the problem?@Stennie

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using a Unix-like shell .. didn't notice the Windows output.  Try `SET MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname"` in the Windows shell.

Comment: ok any way i did the above command but again i faced the another problem i.e `database names cannot contain the character '.'`.So how to solve this problem please help me?.@stennie

Comment: I can restart the server console and again did set path like as you told above and tried to start server as `Meteor` .In this time i face same problem as i posted i.e `Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]`.So why i trouble like this what mistake i did.i didn't have any idea so please help me?.@Stennie